# where is teamviewer 13.0.6634 full screen button

Tags: teamviewer

I am using teamviewer 13. However, I cannot find any ways to switch to full screen. I googled, however seems no one is encountering the problem. I want to switch the session to full screen. However, I cannot find any full screen button again. Anyway to switch to full screen?